# Trigger st.forms when download button is clicked in streamlit, python

Tags: python, streamlit

I've created a streamlit app. I intend to use this app to gather email ids of the users. I want to create a form input whenever someone clicks on the download button for the output they created with my app.
I'm not sure how to use the on_click keyword for this. Let me know if there's any other solution
This is what I had written:

### Helpers

```
import io
import pandas as pd
import streamlit as sl
from PIL import Image
from src import create_qr_code, create_wifi_qr
from streamlit_gsheets import GSheetsConnection
import config

def submitted():
    sl.session_state.submitted = True
def reset():
    sl.session_state.submitted = False
```

### Calling the source function here that generates the image. Replace that with any function you want that returns something

```
gen_btn = tab_gen.button("Generate QR Code")
download_flag = False
if gen_btn == True:
    byte_im, img = create_qr_code(content=gen_content,
                                  border=border,
                                  scale=scale,
                                  fg_color=fg_color,
                                  bg_color=bg_color,
                                  data_fg=data_fg,
                                  data_bg=data_bg,
                                  logo_flag=logo_flag,
                                  logo=logo_image,
                                  bg_flag=bg_flag,
                                  bg_image=bg_image,
                                  bg_url=None,
                                  art_kind=art_kind)
    tab_gen.image(img)
    filename = "xyz.jpg"
```

### Next creating the form here within the tab.

#### When I tried it without session state, the submit button was not returning anything.

```
    with tab_gen.form("email_form"):

        sl.write("Please share your professional email to download the file")
        email = sl.text_input("Professional email", key='email')
        name = sl.text_input("Full Name", key='name')
        # Every form must have a submit button.
        sl.form_submit_button(label="Submit", on_click=submitted)

        df = pd.DataFrame(data=None, columns=['email', 'name'])

    if 'submitted' in sl.session_state:
        if sl.session_state.submitted == True:
            print("Printing inputs :", sl.session_state.email, sl.session_state.name)
            print("Submitted Form")
            data = {
                'email': [sl.session_state.email],
                'name': [sl.session_state.name]
            }
            original = conn.read(spreadsheet=config.EMAIL_SHEET)
            df = pd.concat([original, pd.DataFrame(data)], ignore_index=True)
            conn.update(spreadsheet=config.EMAIL_SHEET, data=df)
            reset()
            download_flag = True

    if download_flag == True:
        tab_gen.download_button("Download", data=byte_im, file_name=filename)
```

[image: screenshot of the download button in app]

Comment: Can you share a runnable code snippet so we can see how you've tried to implement this so far?

Comment: Hi @CarolineFrasca I have added the snippets of what I have written. 
Unfortunately, I'm not able to get it to work as needed.

Comment: That code snippet isn't runnable – can you share a minimal reproducible example? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example